# WebSockets in Rails : Do we have to create a new WebSocketController in our existing application while using the websockets?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, websocket, websocket-rails

I have a chat application [here](https://github.com/huzefahuzu/ChatApp) . I was going through the [wiki](https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails/wiki/WebsocketRails-Controllers) of WebSockets . There the code is described in the ChatController like this :

```
class ChatController < WebsocketRails::BaseController
  def initialize_session
    # perform application setup here
    controller_store[:message_count] = 0
  end
end
```

**My Question** : how should i implement this in my `chatcontroller` which is exteding the `ApplicationController` ? .
Whether i should create a new controller for using the `websockets` or modify the existing `chatcontroller` which should extend the `WebsocketRails`? . I am new to WebSockets so any help regarding this will really help .

Thank you .

Comment: Instead of downvoting , care to atleast answer something. state the reason of downvoting .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer, with relation to the [websocket-rails gem](https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails), as well as Faye and [Plezi](https://github.com/boazsegev/plezi) is YES, you have to create a new controller class, different than the one used by Rails.

Your websocket-rails must inherit `WebsocketRails::BaseController`, while your Rails controller must inherit `ActionController::Base` (usually by inhering you ApplicationController, which inherits this class).

Ruby doesn't support double class inheritance (although Mixins are possible when using modules).

Faye, on the other hand doesn't use the Controller in the same object oriented way and there are more options there. For instance, you COULD map websocket events to your controller CLASS methods, but you might have an issue initializing a Rails controller for each websocket connection, since some of the Controller's internal mechanisms might break. Session info, for instance, will NOT be available and you would probably have to avoid any and all Rails specific methods.

With Plezi, these inheritance issues don't exit, but Plezi automatically creates Http routes to any public methods your Controller has - so your Rails methods will be exposed in a way you didn't intend. Plezi Controllers, on the other hand, can answer both Http and Websockets.

The reason I wrote also about Faye and Plezi is because the websocket-rails gem had last been updated (according the the CHANGELOG) on **March 2014**...

I don't know how well it will survive (or had survived) the latest updates to Rails, but I would recommend moving on.

For now, **November 2015**, Faye is the more common option and Plezi is a new player in the field. I'm Plezi's author.

### Edit (answering the comment)

Both Faye and Plezi should allow one user to send a message to another.

I think Plezi is easiyer to use, but this is because I wrote Plezi. I am sure the person that wrote Faye will think that Faye is easier.

There are a few options about the best way(s) to implement a chat, depending on how you want to do so.

You can look at the plezi application demo code if you install Plezi and run (in your terminal):

```
  $ plezi mini my_chat
```

Here's a quick hack for adding Plezi websocket broadcasting to your existing application.

If I had access to your database, I would have done it a little differently... but it's good enough as a proof of concept... for now.

Add the following line to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'plezi'
```

Create a `plezi_init.rb` file and add it to your `config/initializers` folder. Here is what it hold for now (most of it is hacking the Rails cookie, because I don't have access to your database and I can't add fields):

```
class WebsocketController

    def on_open
        # this is a Hack - replace this with a database token and a cookie.
        return close unless cookies[:_linkedchats_session] # refuse unauthenticated connections
        # this is a Hack - get the user
        @user_id = decrypt_session_cookie(cookies[:_linkedchats_session].dup)['warden.user.user.key'][0][0].to_s
        puts "#{@user_id} is connected"
    end

    def on_message data
        # what do you want to do when you get data?        
    end

    protected

    # this will inform the user that a message is waiting
    def message_waiting msg
        write(msg.to_json) if msg[:to].to_s == @user_id.to_s
    end

    # this is a Hack - replace this later
    # use a token authentication instead (requires a database field)
    def decrypt_session_cookie(cookie)
        key ='4f7fad1696b75330ae19a0eeddb236c123727f2a53a3f98b30bd0fe33cfc26a53e964f849d63ad5086483589d68c566a096d89413d5cb9352b1b4a34e75d7a7b'
        cookie = CGI::unescape(cookie)

        # Default values for Rails 4 apps
        key_iter_num = 1000
        key_size     = 64
        salt         = "encrypted cookie"         
        signed_salt  = "signed encrypted cookie"  

        key_generator = ActiveSupport::KeyGenerator.new(key, iterations: key_iter_num)
        secret = key_generator.generate_key(salt)
        sign_secret = key_generator.generate_key(signed_salt)

        encryptor = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new(secret, sign_secret, serializer: JSON)
        encryptor.decrypt_and_verify(cookie)
    end
end

# IMPORTANT - create the Plezi, route for websocket connections
Plezi.route '/ws', WebsocketController
```

That's almost all the Plezi application you need for this one.

Just add the following line in to your `ChatsController#create` method, just before the `respond_to`:

```
 WebsocketController.broadcast :message_waiting,
          from: @msg.sender_id,
          to: @msg.receiver_id,
          text: @msg.text,
          msg: :chat
```

That's it for the server... Now, the client.

Add the following script to your `chat.html.erb` template (or, because turbo-links might mess up your script's initialization, add the script to your `application.js` file... but you will be refusing a lot of connections until your users log in):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// Your websocket URI should be an absolute path. The following sets the base URI.
// remember to update to the specific controller's path to your websocket URI.
var ws_controller_path = '/ws'; // change to '/controller/path'
var ws_uri = (window.location.protocol.match(/https/) ? 'wss' : 'ws') + '://' + window.document.location.host + ws_controller_path
// websocket variable.
var websocket = NaN
// count failed attempts
var websocket_fail_count = 0
// to limit failed reconnection attempts, set this to a number.
var websocket_fail_limit = NaN


function init_websocket()
{
    if(websocket && websocket.readyState == 1) return true; // console.log('no need to renew socket connection');
    websocket = new WebSocket(ws_uri);
    websocket.onopen = function(e) {
        // reset the count.
        websocket_fail_count = 0
        // what do you want to do now?
    };

    websocket.onclose = function(e) {
        // If the websocket repeatedly you probably want to reopen the websocket if it closes
        if(!isNaN(websocket_fail_limit) && websocket_fail_count >= websocket_fail_limit) {
            // What to do if we can't reconnect so many times?
            return
        };
        // you probably want to reopen the websocket if it closes.
        if(isNaN(websocket_fail_limit) || (websocket_fail_count <= websocket_fail_limit) ) {
            // update the count
            websocket_fail_count += 1;
            // try to reconect
            init_websocket();
        };
    };
    websocket.onerror = function(e) {
        // update the count.
        websocket_fail_limit += 1
        // what do you want to do now?
    };
    websocket.onmessage = function(e) {
        // what do you want to do now?
        console.log(e.data);
        msg = JSON.parse(e.data)
        alert("user id: " + msg.from + " said:\n" + msg.text)
    };
}
// setup the websocket connection once the page is done loading
window.addEventListener("load", init_websocket, false); 

</script>
```

Done.

Comment: Thank you for detailed information sir but the application i have developed is more complex as it communicates with different users on the same page one after another . So , what would work in my case ? Sir , if you can checkout the link of my application that i have mentioned in my question would be very helpfull for me . After that please suggest websockets way or Faye or Plezi . Thank you . :)

Comment: That is awesome . But one question is , you have mentioned to add some code in my `chat.html.erb` , so what about the existing code that i have currently ? . means will it create any kind of conflicts ? . Thank you :)

Comment: @huzefabiyawarwala - There are no conflicts. Your Rails application saves the messages to the database and the Plezi line of code will send the messages as websocket data to the client. They play well together. The only thing is, you can't use `thin` or `puma` or another server. Plezi uses `iodine` as it's server. [`iodine`](https://github.com/boazsegev/iodine) can act also as a Rack server, so your Rails application uses Rack and Plezi uses the server directly (this helps with Http streaming, websockets and more stuff that Rack wasn't designed for).

Comment: ok will surely update you once i am done sir. I very much appreciate your extended help . :)

Comment: I have updated my chat application by the code given by you but it doesn't seems to be working sir , i have uploaded it [here](https://bitbucket.org/huzefahuzu53/chatapp/overview) . please let me know what are the corrections that i need to make to make it working . Thank you . :)

Comment: @huzefabiyawarwala - When I try to see you code I get the message "You do not have access to this repository"... can you make the code public?  ... also, how did you test (you need two browsers and two different users talking to each other). Because of `turbolinks`, try refreshing the chat page or moving the script to `application.js`. also, try to remove the `if` in the `message_waiting` method, to check if users are connected and get updates (maybe user_id recognition isn't working with `devise`)...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94288/discussion-between-huzefa-biyawarwala-and-myst).

Comment: @huzefabiyawarwala - I made some corrections in your application's code and opened "Pull Requests" to help you see the changes and merge the changes into your application.